# Webpack 2.0 how to supress syntax errors?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

Currently using webpack@v2.1.0-beta.25.

I've npm installed standard to standardize JS syntax, and I've also went ahead and run `standard --fix` to catch any misc. errors I haven't caught. However, I'm getting this *extremely* long error message every time I run a webpack command to create a bundle that looks something like this...

[image]

How do I either:

1. fix the standardization problem that's causing it to think I have syntax errors with standard {Preferred Resolve}
2. suppress these syntax error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to include `exclude: /node_nodules/`

Answer (score -1):

Replace `new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()` with `new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()`